# Issue solving a linear differential equation.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, differential

I am currently working through a chapter in my textbook, and it is on solving a form of linear differential equation. I have been trying to figure out what is happening for about 3 hours as of now.

[image]
[image]

I don't understand how $\frac{d}{dt}e^{k(t))}x = 0$, since it says that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{k(t)} = p(t)e^{k(t)}$. Surely this would mean that$\frac{d}{dt}e^{k(t)}x = x*p(t)e^{k(t)}$.

Comment: They have applied the product rule in reverse.

Comment: Mind explaining it further @Casey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from $e^{k(t)}\frac{dx}{dt}+p(t)e^{k(t)}x=0$

Note that $p(t)e^{k(t)}x=\frac{d}{dt}e^{k(t)}$

Therefore, by the product rule

$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{k(t)}x)=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{k(t)})*x+\frac{dx}{dt}e^{k(t)} = p(t)e^{k(t)}x+e^{k(t)}\frac{dx}{dt}=0$

Let me know if this clears up the confusion

Comment: Thank you so much, I dont know how the hell I managed to do the product rule wrong.

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{k(t)}x\right) &= e^{k(t)}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{k(t)}\right)x\\
&= e^{k(t)}\frac{dx}{dt} + p(t)e^{k(t)}x
\end{align*}

according to the product rule. So if we run through the lines in reverse order, we have the derivation.